# Applying modular css on dynamic content like matTooltip

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-components

In an angular component, I'm creating a tooltip:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './column-edit.template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./column-edit.style.scss']
})
export class myclass {
  public dateFormatTooltip = "This and this \n and that as well";
}
```

In `column-edit.template.html` I have this:

```
<i class="fa fa-info" 
[matTooltip]="dateFormatTooltip" 
matTooltipPosition="after" 
matTooltipHideDelay="999999">
</i>
```

And in `column-edit.style.scss` I have this:

```
:host {
    .mat-tooltip {
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
}
```

The problem here is that this css doesn't get applied to the `.mat-tooltip` element because it's dynamic, at the time of rendering the HTML that element doesn't exist. I googled and found that this problem has been [reported before](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/984) and I tried a couple of solutions but neither worked:

I tried using `/deep/` even though it's deprecated just to see if I'm on the right path or not:

```
:host /deep/ {
    .mat-tooltip {
        white-space: pre-line;
    }
}
```

And I also tried adding the css directly into the component rather than in a scss file:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './column-edit.template.html',
    styles: ['.mat-tooltip {white-space: pre-line}']
})
```

Neither solution worked, I'm hoping there's a work around this and better yet a way to add formatted HTML in angular material's tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the answer, but here are the things I would try:

Remove the `:host` selector, so that it's just:

```css
.mat-tooltip {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

You've probably tried that, though.

Next option - try removing the view encapsulation:

```ts
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-selector',
    templateUrl: './column-edit.template.html',
    styles: ['.mat-tooltip {white-space: pre-line}'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And then finally, if none of the options stated above work, try adding a custom class to the tooltip via the `matTooltipClass` input:

```html
<i class="fa fa-info" 
    [matTooltip]="dateFormatTooltip"
    [matTooltipClass]="{'prewrap': true}"
    [matTooltipPosition]="after"
    [matTooltipHideDelay]="3000">
</i>
```

That should add a `prewrap` class to the tooltip, which you could then try styling.

That's the best I can offer.